# Should I pass an int array to a function by reference?

Tags: arrays, c, performance, reference

A basic idea of what I'm talking about is below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunction(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        arr[i] *= 2;
}


void someFunctionByReference(int *arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        arr[i] *= 2;
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 0};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    someFunction(arr, n);
    
    int arr2[] = {5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 0};
    int n2 = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);
    someFunctionByReference(arr2, n2);
    return 0;

}
```

Both of these functions (as I see it) do the same thing. They even contain the same code. However, I would like to understand what the differences between the two are, and if there is a proper and improper way of doing this in certain scenarios.

Comment: C doesn't have references. And in C when you declare an argument as `int arr[]` the compiler treats it as `int *arr`, so both functions are called with pointers (to the first element of the array).

Comment: `int *arr` is equivalent to `int arr[]` when declaring parameters in function prototypes, and you cannot pass an array to a function in C (unless the array is embedded in a struct or union).

Comment: Adding to this [from S.P.D.], both of your functions will generate _exactly_ the same [asm] code. The caller will pass `arr` as [effectively] `&arr[0]`. Think about it: There isn't much use to passing an array by _value_ (e.g. `int arr[1000000]` would pass/push 1,000,000 `int` values if it _did_ pass by value). And, if you did change the array, it wouldn't persist. It's _not_ like a scalar (e.g. `n`) which _is_ pass by value. Personally, I prefer the `int *arr` form for the argument.

Comment: The same is _not_ true for a `struct`. With: `struct myary { int arr[1000]; }; void func(struct myary arr) { ... }` _is_ pass-by-value. And, it _would_ push 1000 `int` values onto the stack. That's why almost all functions are defined with pointers to `struct`: (e.g.) `void func(struct myary *arr) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both function invocations and definitions are identical.  Under most circumstances, an expression of array type will “decay” to an expression of pointer type and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a` - the parameter is a pointer, not an array object.  This is because when you pass an array expression as a function argument, the function will actually receive a pointer value, not an array.

This behavior is unique to array expressions - other aggregate types like `struct` and `union` types do not “decay” in this manner. If you pass a struct type with an array member, the contents of the array member will be copied over.

And this is not an example of “pass by reference”, either.  C passes all function parameters by value, no exceptions.  Sometimes those values are pointers.  This particular quirk is simply fallout from how C treats arrays.